# If $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $F,$ then there exists a scalar $\beta \in F$ such that $X+\beta I$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was reading Lemma $1$ mentioned in [this paper.](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf) The proof of the lemma seems to use the fact that

> If $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $F,$ then there exists a scalar $\beta \in F$ such that $X+\beta I$ is invertible.
>   where $F$ is a subfield of the complex numbers.

Attempt :

If $X$ is invertible, choose $\beta=0.$

If $X$ is non-invertible, then there exists an invertible $P$ such that $PX=R$ where $R$ is the row-reduced echelon form of $X.$

Now, choose $\beta \ne 0$ such that $R\ne -\beta P.$

Now consider the system $(X+\beta I)Y=0$ where $Y\in F^{n\times 1}.$ If we show $Y=0$ is the only solution we are done.

Multiplying the system by $P,$ we get $RY+\beta PY=0.$

But $RY+\beta PY\ne -\beta PY +\beta PY=0.$

This implies $Y=0$ is the only solution.

I don't trust my last step in the argument. Is there something wrong in this proof? If this is wrong please provide a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function $\det(X+\beta I):F\rightarrow F$.

This is a polynomial function. Thus has only finitely many roots so there are infinitely many $\beta$ in $F$ assuming our field is not a finite field such that the function is non zero at that point.

Comment: Is there any elementary method? Polynomials have not been introduced to me yet.

Comment: I can not think of any other elementary method. Hope some one else might help you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Consider the 2*2 matrix in the field with two elements with a one in the upper left corner and zeroes everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, it's false for finite fields

Comment: Thanks! Will it do if I constrain $F$ to be a subfield of complex numbers? Or do you have something general

Answer (score 0):

I would put it as follows.

If $\bf X$ is not invertible, then its (column) vectors are not all independent.
So it will have $m<n$  null vectors $\bf Y_{n,m}$ and $n-m$ eigenvectors $\bf Z_{n,n-m}$, all independent.
$$
{\bf X}\;{\bf y}_k  = {\bf 0}\quad {\bf X}\;{\bf z}_k  = \lambda _k \,{\bf z}_k 
$$

Then
$$
\left( {{\bf X} + \beta \,{\bf I}} \right)\;{\bf y}_k  = \beta {\bf y}_k \quad \left( {{\bf X} + \beta \,{\bf I}} \right)\;{\bf y}_k  = \left( {\beta  + \lambda _k } \right){\bf y}_k 
$$
and $\left( {{\bf X} + \beta \,{\bf I}} \right)$ is invertible for all $\beta \ne \lambda_k$.